# How to check if a view has children

Tags: android, android-view

Is there a way to check if a view has children? For example...

```
boolean bool = view.hasChildren(); //returns true if view has one or more children
```

I need to know this because I have an empty layout I'm adding new views to dynamically and I need to know if the layout is empty or not.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Is there a way to check if a view has children

Assuming is a subclass of `ViewGroup`, you can use `getChildCount()`. E.g.

```
 public static boolean hasChildren(ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    return viewGroup.getChildCount() > 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

We also need to check whether view have child views or not.
For example,

```
    private int getViewsCount(View view){
        try{
            return ((ViewGroup) view).getChildCount();
        }catch(Exception e){
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

Some views like TextView and ImageView can't be cast to ViewGroup so we need to catch that exception to avoid runtime errors.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
for(int index=0; index<((ViewGroup)viewGroup).getChildCount(); ++index) {
    View nextChild = ((ViewGroup)viewGroup).getChildAt(index);
}
```